# Moving kinematic bodies with a dynamic velocity in Pymunk

Tags: python, pygame, pymunk

I just started learning Pymunk so I'm quite confused, any help would be appreciated! I want to create a kinematic platform whose position is a sine wave,

```py
x_plate(t) = A*np.sin(w*t)
```

subsequently with a velocity of

```py
v_plate(t) = A*w*np.cos(w*t)
```

I'm quite confused so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Edit:
I found a property called **velocity_func** that lets you set the body's velocity, problem is the parameters to set are

```py
body.velocity_func = func(body, gravity, damping, dt)
```

and I'm not quite sure how to proceed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can assign position and velocity manually, or you can use the callback function, velocity_func, you already found.

If you use the callback you need to define a function and assign it to the velocity_func property of the body, like is described in the doc: http://www.pymunk.org/en/latest/pymunk.html#pymunk.Body.velocity_func

```
import pymunk
body = pymunk.Body(1,2, body_type=pymunk.Body.KINEMATIC)
def sine_wave(body, gravity, damping, dt):
    body.velocity = ... # a vector of the velocity x and y.

body.velocity_func = sine_wave
```

A full example of using this method is available in the planet demo: https://github.com/viblo/pymunk/blob/e7b05ab07defcc77f94e8fc49bcab5e223ff143d/examples/planet.py#L40

The nice with this solution is that Pymunk will automatically call this function each step.

Another way in case you dont like the callback is to just update the position and velocity manually each step. There is an example of this in the platformer example code here https://github.com/viblo/pymunk/blob/master/examples/platformer.py#L262

```
...
space.step(dt)
body.position = ... # position x and y.
body.velocity = ... # a 2d vector of the velocity.
...
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply! I've been trying it out and I'm still a bit confused. Does the self-defined function to be assigned to the body.velocity_func property have to be in terms of gravity, damping, and dt?

Comment: The function needs to be of the exact format, accepting body, gravity, damping and dt as arguments, regardless if you use them or not. If you need some more data inside the function, you need to give it to the function in some other way. For example with a global variable or a custom property on the body.